# Can't fixed Error(43,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can't find:

> Error(43,1) PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

and:

> Error(43,19): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Please help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEAM_pkg AS    
procedure displayInfo(tid TEAM.team_ID%type) is
dis teamrecord;
chec varchar(20);
BEGIN

SELECT tname INTO chec FROM Team 
  WHERE team.team_id = tid; 
  IF chec IS NULL  then
  raise team_not_found;
  else
select * into dis from team where team_id = tid;
dbms_output.put_line(dis.teamid ||' '||dis.tname||' '||dis.rk||' '||dis.ct);

end if;
EXCEPTION
WHEN team_not_found THEN
Rollback; -- Oracle performs an implicit rollback once and exception is  raised.
dbms_output.put_line('Team not Found!');
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
Rollback; -- Oracle performs an implicit rollback once and exception is raised.
dbms_output.put_line('Team not Found!');
end;
```

Comment: select * into dis from team where team_id = tid;

Comment: Your error occurs on line 43 but the code you posted has no line 43.  What line does the error occur on?  You're catching a `team_not_found` exception that you haven't declared that would throw a compilation error.  `teamrecord` is also not defined-- is that a variable of type `team%rowtype`?

Comment: my code is too long to post, the exception is handled, yes teamrecord is variable of type. actually the error moves from line to line. Like if i delete the block where the error is at, then it appear somewhere else

Comment: But is the `teamrecord` type either `team%rowtype`, or at least a record type that exactly matches the `team` layout? If not the `select ... into dis` could get this error. But it's hard to tell with partial information. Try to get it down to the shortest procedure or block that generates the error.

Comment: you can save 1 select when you get all values instead of tname only `select * into dis from team where team_id = tid`; why do you rollback, when you make no WRITE operations? please use identation to make your code more readable...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing END of PACKAGE BODY.